# groovy: MissingPropertyException: No such property:

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am facing an issue when shell command is returning non existent value because output produces no value as `env.version == '1.0.0.232'`-->false, does not exist in pypy server.

but when `env.version == '1.0.0.23'`--> true, does  exist in pypy server, code proceed as normal.

Jenkins code:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'master' }
    parameters {
        string(defaultValue: 'DEV', description: '', name: 'ENV', trim: true)  
        string(defaultValue: 'sys', description: '', name: 'platform_type', trim: true)
        string(defaultValue: 'server2', description: '', name: 'dev_app_host', trim: true)
        string(defaultValue: 'server1', description: '', name: 'dev_xbar_host', trim: true)
        string(defaultValue: '1.0.0.23', description: '', name: 'VERSION', trim: true)
        booleanParam(defaultValue: false, description: 'force build if possible', name: 'force_build')
    }
    environment {
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('build') {
                steps {
                    script {
                        try{
                            try{
                                def version_exists = sh(script: "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ansible@pip_server ls /var/pypi/packages/dev/ | grep ${env.app_module_name}  | grep ${env.VERSION}" , returnStdout: true) ?: 'no_files_found'
                                echo version_exists
                                echo version_exists.inspect()
                                echo version_exists.dump()
                                } catch(e){
                                    echo "inner exception: ${e}"
                                }
                        } catch (e) {
                            echo "outer exception: ${e}"
                            currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Jenkins relevant long:

```
+ grep 1.0.0.232
+ grep dvmt_event_processor
+ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ansible@pip_server ls /var/pypi/packages/dev/
[Pipeline] echo
inner exception: hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 1
[Pipeline] echo
outer exception: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: version_exists for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

PS: can the shell command be improved upon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` returns status code 1 when it finds no matching lines. Jenkins interprets a non-0 status as the script failing, so it throws a `hudson.AbortException` rather than assigning the output to `version_exists`.

Try something like this:

```
def version_exists = sh( " ... | grep ${env.VERSION} || echo not_found", returnStdout: true)
```